# Understanding Javascript(Mono-Threading)

Tags: javascript, multithreading, theory

I have the next question, I've heard that JS is a mono-thread language, but how that can be if we use async and await, I mean if we are doing a code that have Asyncronic instances running they have to be running in different threads, could you explain to me, probably I'm wrong but I want to know why, thanks.